# What is difference between .toString() and (String) cast in Java

Tags: java, classcastexception

I want to read a value from the session object which returns `Object` type.
I know that the object has either `true`/`false` value.
I would like to convert that value into `boolean` type. So I have the following code.

```
session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue"); // It returns Object type
```

Below throws an Exception.

```
boolean myBoolVal = Boolean.parseBoolean((String) session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue"));
```

Below works properly.

```
boolean myBoolVal = Boolean.parseBoolean(session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue").toString());
```

Actually, I don't understand why option 1 is not working ?

Comment: This here might be of interst, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328661/explicit-vs-implicit-call-of-tostring

Comment: what is the value of session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue").getClass()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the runtime type of the instance returned by `session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue")` is not a `String`, casting it to `String` throws a `ClassCastException`.

On the other hand, `session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue").toString()` always works (assuming `session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue")` is not null), since all Objects have an implementation of the `toString()` method.

BTW, since `session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue")` doesn't return a `String`, it is likely that it returns a `Boolean` (since you expect `Boolean.parseBoolean()` to work), so if that is the case, instead of converting it to `String` and then to `Boolean`, you can just cast it to `Boolean` :

```
Boolean myBoolVal = (Boolean) session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set in the session object any object you want and associate to it a key. Any object means any object of any class. As any class is a possibly indirect sub class of `Object` then type is `Object` in `set` and `get`.

When you retrieve an object via `get` it is simply typed as `Object` but is certainly of some subclass. (Down)casting it to `String` may fails (an exception is thrown saying that the cast/conversion can't be realized) if the original class is not `String`. Seems to be the case for your option 1.

Option 2 works because any `Object` instance has a method `toString()` that can be called to get a `String` representation of the object (mainly useful for onscreen presentation of it). Then you `parse` that representation (probably `"true"` or `"false"`) to obtain a `boolean` of value `true` or `false`.

So if you want your option 1 to work, as your object is probably a `Boolean` instance, you can use:

```
boolean myBoolVal = (Boolean)session.getAttribute("MyKeyValue");
```

Comment: The `static` method  `Boolean.parseBoolean(String)` returns a `boolean` not a `Boolean`.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-  There is no unboxing here.

Comment: Also note that the unboxing would throw a NullPointerException if the value is `null` (as does the OPs `toString`-version, of course).